# Width não aumenta mais que 283px BootStrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Olá, possuo um formulário onde tenho um `TextArea`. Porém o `Width` não passa dos `283px`.
Quando diminuo, o mesmo diminui corretamente, agora quando aumento, não funciona.

Seto o tamanho como `400px`, porém, ao inspecionar o código pelo Google, vejo que possuo apenas `283px`.

Segue o form em questão:

```
  <div class="container">
    <h4> Descriçao da Solicitação</h4>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Descricao, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:400px;", placeholder = "Digite a descrição de sua solicitação aqui" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sLotacao)
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <h5> Requerido a concessão da vantagem assinada nos termos da legislação em vigor aplicável ao assunto.</h5>
</div>
```

Como proceder?

Comment: Como fica o `TextArea` no código `Html`?

Comment: Ele fica editável, porém só consigo alterar o height( arrastando com o mouse), o width nao muda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reproduzi a sua situação aqui em um projeto de teste e não obtive o mesmo erro.
Seu form pode estar herdando o essa largura de algum CSS ou alguma função jQuery por exemplo.

De todo o modo, a linha abaixo de código pode acabar ajudando por conta do atributo `!important` o qual inseri junto a declaração do estilo.

```
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Descricao, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:400px !important", @placeholder = "Digite a descrição de sua solicitação aqui" })
```

Comment: Com o !important também não funcionou. Vou verificar o caso da herança, para verificar e já posto aqui.

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Seu site está publicado em algum link?

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Eu estava herdando do arquivo Site.css que o MVC cria automaticamente.
Alterei a informação no mesmo, e funcionou perfeitamente.